# Draw a bezier curve(s) with a set of points from a vector

Tags: c++, graphics, bezier, curves

I was wondering what would be the best and less complicated way of drawing a bezier curve in c++ with a set of points (roughly 100+ points) that are stored inside a vector
From my understanding:
-Bezier curves consist of 4 control points, the points in the middle dictate the direction/tangent of the curve

Would one possible method be to breakdown the points into different segments and from each segment determine the control points and tangents?

Answer (score 1):

It is called a cubic spline and if you search you might find some C++ code for it. I used the free Fortran code from [Numerical Recipes Online](http://www.nrbook.com/a) and ported it to C# with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

> Would one possible method be to
>   breakdown the points into different
>   segments and from each segment
>   determine the control points and
>   tangents?

Yes, basically one connects the line segments end-to-end such that the slope approaching the end of the line segment is equal on both sides of the connection point. This is called a cubic spline. You can find algorithms for this [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation).